# About writing a finit family of sets in terms of pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $F$ be a finite collection of sets, how can I construct a finite collection $F'$ of pairwise disjoint sets such that every set in $F$ is union of elements of $F'$ ?; or how can I prove the existence of such $F'$ ?

When $F$ is contains only 2 or 3 sets it's easy to find $F'$, I have no idea how to do it in the general case

Comment: I cannot think on an easy expression but maybe this helps. If you know how to prove that given a finite family of sets you can construct a family of disjoint sets whose union is the same, then you can construct the families $F_n$='intersections of n sets in $F$', and consider the sets inside those families are pairwise disjoint. If you need I can make the construction more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Induction on $|F|$ works. If $|F|=1$, take $F'=F$. Suppose $F=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ for $n \geq 2$, and let $F'$ be the finite disjoint collection for $\{A_1,\ldots,A_{n-1}\}$ (by induction). Then adding the set $A_n \setminus (\cup_{S \in F'}S)$ to $F'$ gives a suitable family for $F$.